# The usual WP Permalink problem

Tags: wordpress

I've setup a new Ubuntu 16.04-x86_64 VPS and transferred my WP site over from a Centos 6 VPS.

All went well except that I can't get permalinks to work in WP. I've tried eveything imaginable. Been at it for a couple of days! Configuired, reconfigured, searched, changed, rebooted Apache2 and the VPS what seems like 200 times - but no love. Something tells me I'm missing something very obvious here. mod_rewrite is enabled and working.

I'm working from the command line and Filezilla SFTP. Here's are my config files

TIA for any suggestions.

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # changed from None to FileInfo
        AllowOverride FileInfo
       Require all granted
```

---

```
root@server1:~# sudo a2enmod rewrite
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_AU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Module rewrite already enabled
```

---

.htaccess set to 666. WP is in the /en folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

When you install Apache, the mod rewrite is not enabled by default. You might need to enable mod rewrite by typing the following command in terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

For more information look into 
https://www.techiediaries.com/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-404-error/.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into that trouble before with some of my sites when I transferred them to another server.

Here's what I did. edit your `apache2.conf` at `/etc/apache2/` folder.

Run the following command:

`nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Scroll down and look for this section with a comment:

```
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
```

Make sure that this is the one in there:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For short, grant it. For your permalinks not to fail.

-Dave